# Returning response from cache when there is no connection to server

Tags: javascript, caching, service-worker

With help of service worker, I want to return response from cache if there is no connection to server. Then, if there is no right response in cache, I want return custom response.

For now, I have this code:

```
this.addEventListener('fetch', function (event) {
    event.respondWith(
        timeout(5000, fetch(event.request)).catch(function() {
            return caches.match(event.request);
        })
    );
});
```

I want to have something like this:

```
this.addEventListener('fetch', function (event) {
    event.respondWith(
        timeout(5000, fetch(event.request)).catch(function() {
            caches.match(event.request).then(function(cacheResponse) {
                return cacheResponse;
            }).catch(function () {
                return new Response('No cache found');
            })
        })
    );
});
```

or even better would be

```
this.addEventListener('fetch', function (event) {
    event.respondWith(
        timeout(5000, fetch(event.request)).catch(function() {
            caches.match(event.request).then(function(cacheResponse) {
                return cacheResponse;
            }).catch(function () {
                return caches.match(offlineMessageUrl);
            })
        })
    );
});
```

but it is not working.

Comment: plunker/jsfiddle/codepen? put one together?

Comment: how can one fiddle a service worker?

Comment: I think you can by putting your service worker in a separate jsfiddle. E.g. https://jsfiddle.net/zalun/d10vsucu/ and https://jsfiddle.net/zalun/d80qawf9/.

Comment: What is the point of putting it on fiddle? I just want someone to point where i'm doing wrong - with first sample it will return cached page or "undefined" - I just want to check if response from cache is undefined and then return my own response.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation of the [Cache.match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Cache/match) function, the promise is always resolved. It is resolved with a Response object or with undefined if no match is found. You could try this:-

```
    this.addEventListener('fetch', function (event) {
        event.respondWith(
            caches.match(event.request).then(function(cacheResponse) {
                return cacheResponse || new Response('No cache found');
            }).catch(function () {
                return new Response('No cache found');
            })
        );
    });
```